# Weird jQuery toggle() break in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I've never seen this issue before myself, and I've done a search with all the terms I can possibly think of that this could crop up under (toggle issue FF, toggle jQuery working by itself, etc etc). The initial developer of this website has left and I've just taken over the end of it before it launches. The HTML/WP PHP for this is:

```
<div class="unterzo">
<h2 class="buttone">AUTO-CALLS</h2>
<div class="toggle">
EDIT:
<form name="publication_dropdown" method="get" action="">
    <select name="dropdown" onchange="window.location.href=this.form.dropdown.options[this.form.dropdown.selectedIndex].value">
        <option value="">Select file</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/example.html">BAC 18_APR_2013</option>
    </select>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery for it is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery(".unterzo").hover(function(){
         jQuery(this).children('.toggle').toggle(400); //Wordpress only works with full jQuery, not $.
     });
  });
</script>
```

Really basic stuff.

This works fine in Chrome/Safari (yet to check in IE...). In Firefox (V 20.0 for Mac & Windows), when you hover over the div, it opens as normal. When you click the dropdown, it's fine but if you try selecting one of the dropdown options, the div starts to open and close repeatedly by itself. There are no errors in the console of Firebug so it's difficult to debug. I made a video screen capture of the problem at hand (see below).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Vxd7FH6bQY

I was wondering, has anyone come across this issue before? Any ideas what's causing it? Is it fixable?

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML rather than the PHP?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Added above. :)

Comment: Can you put a break point on the `jQuery(this).children('.toggle')` line in FireBug and verify that 1) you get there when you click 9as opposed to hover) 2) you get there only once - if you get there twice, it'd toggle the `DIV` back.

Comment: `jQuery.hover(..)` expects two parameters.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy Added that breakpoint. It's saying only that there's a mouseleave event fired when you try selecting one of the `<option>`. Which would surely just close the div. But that doesn't explain the freak-out though, right? :/

Comment: I made a quick [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PQUFF/). From what I can see it freaks out because you're showing the new element, that gets the mouse over it, causing another `hover` event to bubble up to the main `<div>` element.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Cheers for that. Any ideas on how to go about stopping that? Or will I have to take a different approach?